# Group of invertible elements in a degree 4 central simple algebra with symplectic involution with norm in a center

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, spin-geometry, clifford-algebras, quaternion-algebras

Let $A$ be a central simple algebra of degree 4 (i.e. dimension 16) over a field $F$ with $\mathrm{char}(F) \neq 2$. It is known that any such algebra is a tensor product $D_1 \otimes D_2$ of two quaternion algebras $D_1, D_2$ over $F$, and I'm interested in the case when both $D_1$ and $D_2$ do not split over $F$. Also, assume that there is a symplectic involution $\sigma: A \to A$ on $A$. It is also known that the above two quaternion algebras (regarded as subalgebras of $A$) are $\sigma$-invariant (Rowen, "Central Simple Algebras", Israel J. of Math, 1978). Hence we can consider the involution $\sigma$ as $\sigma(x_1 \otimes x_2):= \sigma_1(x_1) \otimes \sigma_2(x_2)$ where $x_i \in D_i$ and $\sigma_i = \sigma|_{D_i}$.

Now, I wonder if there's an easy way to describe the following group:

$$
G = \{x \in (D_1 \otimes D_2)^\times : N(x):= x\cdot \sigma(x) \in F\}
$$

with the embedding $F \hookrightarrow D_1 \otimes D_2$.
Here the meaning of "easy" could be vague - it would be great if one can find a group that can be expressed as some matrix groups. For example, when both $D_1$ and $D_2$ splits and $A \simeq M_4(F)$, we can show that $G \simeq \mathrm{GSp}(V_4)$ for some 4-dimensional symplectic vector space $V_4$.
In fact, the group $G$ is a general spin group of some 5-dimensional quadratic space $(V, q)$, and the above results follows from some structure theorems of (even) Clifford algebras (e.g. See Lam, "Introduction to quadratic forms over fields"). So my question can be rephrased as - finding a nice description of a general spin group of a quadratic space $(V, q)$ when $C^+(V) \simeq D_1 \otimes D_2$.

Currently, I have the following statements/facts that might be helpful to answer my question:

- There exists a maximal biquadratic field extension $K = F(\sqrt{d_1}, \sqrt{d_2})$ embeds in $A$.
- If $D_1$ splits, $\sigma_1$ is a quaternion conjugation on $D_1$, and $\sigma_2$ is an orthogonal involution, then the resulting group $G$ can be described as a certain subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_2(D)$.
- The dimension of $G$ (over $F$) is 11.

Comment: You probably also want to require that $A$ has period $2$ (in the Brauer group), otherwise $D_1$ and $D_2$ cannot exist.

Comment: @UriyaFirst It seems that it follows from the existence of first kind involution on $A$. It is mentioned in Amitsur et al. "Division algebras of degree 4 and 8 with involution" (as a result of Albert), with comments that the fact (degree 4 division algebras with symplectic involution is a tensor product of two quaternion subalgebras stable under the involution) is proven by Rowen.